# Is there a way to restore a previous version of a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I frequently use the right-click / Modify option in SQL Server Management Studio to pull up existing code in stored procedures in order to reuse the code. Only, this time I did that but forgot to remove the ALTER PROC piece of the code and modified an existing procedure.

Is there a way to restore the last version of a stored procedure without restoring the entire database? I have a saved .sql file that I can use to restore it, but I'm not sure how old that file is compared to the most recent version of the procedure.

Also, I'm not a DBA, more of a Jr-ish SQL Developer. And our DBA is out for a couple weeks :)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's one of the reasons to put your database under source control - [1](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/), [2](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/index), [3](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-source-control.aspx)...

Comment: You don't have it in TEST DB? Usually you would develop it in a test sytem and then move it to LIVE system once it's been fully tested.

Comment: As the others have said, best hope you have a back-up DB or some other non-production environment that hasn't been changed.

Comment: Aside from what others said, I'd check to see if someone set up DDL triggers for logging these changes. That DBA that's our on leave would know.

Comment: if you have a plugin such SQL Complete from devart it caches all the query windows you where working on for the past few days and then you can reopen them.